# How to calculate defect severity index?

Tags: testing

Lets say me defect severity levels are  4 (Critical), 3 (Serious), 2 (Medium), 1 (Low). The total number of defects is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following steps

1)We assign a number to each severity as : Blocker=9, Critical=8, Major=3, Minor=2 , Trivial=1

2)Then we multiply the number of issues in each category by the assigned number as:(Num of Blocker * 9) + (Number of Critical issue * 8)

3)Then we divide by the  Total issue count

ex: ( (Num of Blocker * 9) + (Number of Critical issue * 8) + (Number of Major issue *3) + (Minor issue count * 2) + (Trivial issue count * 1) ) /Total issue count

Comment: How do you make a decision based on the value you get for DSI? any benchmark?

Comment: Typically the benchmark for a mature product is set to exclude any major issues (assuming major designation refers to a defect of a feature with no work around and is observable by the consumer).  Thus in the above example: The benchmark would be a DSI of 2.0 or less.

Answer (score 0):

@hirosht Defect Severity Index provides a measurement of the quality of a product under test. So in multiple test iterations if we can identify that the DSI drop, that **may** indicate that the quality of the product/feature is increasing. However, having said that, the numbers may mislead us and we should not take this as an indication of increasing quality as we need to also take into consideration the number of defects logged per iteration and the severity of the defects identified in each cycle and make our decision.